# How to remove the trailing ` in StringForm["Mean `1`", 2.2]?

Tags: string-manipulation

How to remove the trailing `  in the following?

```
StringForm["Mean `1`", 2.2]
```

produces

```
Mean 2.2`
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `` ` `` you're seeing is the [`NumberMarks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberMarks) that Mathematica uses to print real numbers in [`InputForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputForm) and [`FullForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm). You can suppress it with one of the following methods:

```
StringForm["Mean `1`", StandardForm[2.2]]
StringForm["Mean `1`", Style[2.2, NumberMarks->False]]
```

> Mean 2.2
>
> Mean 2.2

If you're not married to [`StringForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringForm), you could also use [`Row`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Row):

```
Row[{"Mean ", 2.2}]
```

> Mean 2.2

or [`StringTemplate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringTemplate):

```
StringTemplate["Mean `a`"] @ <|"a"->2.2|>
```

> "Mean 2.2"